# Ошибка при установке модуля ximgproc для OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Устанавливаю OpenCV 3.4.9 на 32 бита. Вместе с ней ставлю модуль ximgproc. После сборки в visual studio 2019 показывает следующие ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

собираю через CMake. Делал все как обычно. Только в OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH прописал путь к модулю ximgproc, который скачал с https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем связаны данные ошибки и как их исправить?

Comment: Ну так открой файл да посмотри чего ему не хватает. Даже ошибки на русском написаны.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков дело в том, что я все делал по туториалу. По сути, CMake должен сам докинуть все нужные файлы. А тут не понятно, что ему не хватает. Посмотрел сейчас, этих файлов вообще нет

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Решил данную задачу. Поскольку я ставил OpenCV 3.4.9, нужно на гитхабе выбрать ветку 3.4 (не master!)